# Can't get asp .net core 2.2 to validate my JWT

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

(TL;DR: check the last update)

The first issue with this is that the API has changed between the different versions of .net core.

The second one is that every example I find online is slightly different with not real authoritative answer as to what does what; rather I keep finding posts with 'oh, changing this worked for me', but it looks like everyone is, like me, experimenting with it rather than having a full understanding.

Anyhow, here is the code:

```
        Services.AddAuthentication(A =>
        {
            A.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            A.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(O =>
        {
            O.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            O.SaveToken = true;
            O.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AuthJWTPublicKey)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

I have a valid JWT but any call to my controller results in an immediate error 401.

I have tried to decorate the controller with:

> [Authorize]
>
> [Authorize(Roles = "offline_access")]
>
> [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes =
>   JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "offline_access")]

but no luck

The JWT content is:

```
{  
   "jti":"837c2dd1-cca5-491e-84a4-b17429366df5",
   "exp":1558355152,
   "nbf":0,
   "iat":1558354852,
   "iss":"xxxx",
   "aud":"account",
   "sub":"4ed1c313-c692-44db-86d3-7605f3e2c2c1",
   "typ":"Bearer",
   "azp":"test-app",
   "auth_time":1558354850,
   "session_state":"e40c9a95-ae8a-4d6e-b2a4-ad5e833867ea",
   "acr":"1",
   "realm_access":{  
      "roles":[  
         "offline_access",
         "uma_authorization"
      ]
   },
   "resource_access":{  
      "account":{  
         "roles":[  
            "manage-account",
            "manage-account-links",
            "view-profile"
         ]
      }
   },
   "scope":"openid email profile",
   "email_verified":true,
   "name":"firstd6d05 last29954",
   "preferred_username":"xxxx",
   "given_name":"firstd6d05",
   "family_name":"last29954",
   "email":"xxxx",
   "group":[  
      "/Administrators"
   ]
}
```

My goal is purely to verify the signature of the JWT (and eventually it's expiration) and have access to the token in the controller.

I am passing the JWT through the header, under 'Authorization' and with the text 'Bearer' in front of the token.

What am I missing?

---

Following the answer below, I did the following change:

I added:

```
Services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
```

and then added the following class with a break

```
internal class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

but I am still getting a 401 with the Keycloak token; so it looks like it doesn't get to the claims transformer before being rejected.

---

I added the debug output of ASP.

It is at: https://pastebin.com/qvGsQG6j

The relevant part seems to be:

```
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
          => ConnectionId:0HLN4CPASJL8F => RequestId:0HLN4CPASJL8F:00000001 RequestPath:/helpers/log => Test.WebControllers.HelpersController.GetLog (Test)
          Authorization failed.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Info:Authorization failed.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Info:Authorization failed.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
          => ConnectionId:0HLN4CPASJL8F => RequestId:0HLN4CPASJL8F:00000001 RequestPath:/helpers/log => Test.WebControllers.HelpersController.GetLog (Test)
          Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Info:Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Info:Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
          => ConnectionId:0HLN4CPASJL8F => RequestId:0HLN4CPASJL8F:00000001 RequestPath:/helpers/log => Test.WebControllers.HelpersController.GetLog (Test)
```

This specific line may explain the issue:

> Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'

but 'failed' seems a bit vague to me.

---

Last test:

I have this token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.y42RUvMM69aDTvCydoU3mOKu2giub6OvKpd-RNVmom4
```

with the key:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjayVuqZOuKK38rhsRwrRGzVcv/7b4fHXrzpol3K5TTAPttNUaQvCKQD7BQN+V8nvkBsQcxPk5ONnxzbFb/npENC4UtwK5J6iiVrinE7sDrWZQNo9LkwbuG9x0fuuf8U3H2CnwZEfFaf2kbU1v7XosNGi+aYASupvhwoiJtK+17ZPloxSQy3Qny2tQWi7Dh/Cr5+m5JBy6HeGLq2cq+oalFYzrGGmQXndLtJpBZgrPd7nR6lJSMiRcJtcpxTJbYTEVVXoB0SR1bPmYYB/6y7klVDVedTow+1mwZrDMrbRiTBPSifCIBs3rxLQaL207blg+kj+EVLED5fZSOBlOyTOYQIDAQAB
```

it decodes to (as tested by jwt.io):

```
{
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "my name",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "no@email.com",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/expiration": "05/31/2019 00:13:20",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/sid": "7cacf7b5-8669-469e-9885-d4804f28cc4a",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims/actor": "d2f6b724-a4f9-4bdd-a647-4d3e1a5968de",
  "nbf": 1559175200,
  "exp": 1559261600,
  "iss": "test",
  "aud": "test-app"
}
```

it is generated by the following code:

```
        var Expiration = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        var Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,          "my name"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,         "no@email.com"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration,    Expiration.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid,           Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Actor,         Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        });

        var Token = new JwtSecurityToken
        (
            issuer:             "test",
            audience:           "test-app",
            claims:             Identity.Claims,
            notBefore:          DateTime.UtcNow,
            expires:            Expiration,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_JwtRsaPublicKey)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );

        var TokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(Token);
        return TokenString;
```

In asp, I have the following code:

```
                    Services.AddAuthentication(A =>
                    {
                        A.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        A.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                    .AddJwtBearer(O =>
                    {
                        O.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        O.SaveToken = true;
                        O.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                        O.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AuthJWTPublicKey)),
                            ValidateIssuer = false,
                            ValidateAudience = false
                        };
                    });
```

and I have a controller method with:

> ```
>   [Authorize]
> ```

But I keep getting a 401, no matter what I try, I get a 401...

Even if I set ValidateIssuerSigningKey to false. I get a 401

The setup is:

In ConfigureServices, I have:

```
Services.AddMvc()
and the code above
```

In Configure, I have:

```
Application.UseAuthentication();
Application.UseMvc(Routes => { Routes.MapRoute("default_route", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"); });
```

Comment: did you use JwtTokenBuilder and can you add the part where you create jwt data.

Comment: The token was created by keycloak

Comment: There is a good post about jwt usage in net core and it uses JwtTokenBuilder => https://medium.com/@engr.mmohsin/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-role-based-authentication-authorization-with-custom-tables-and-identity-401c898d9ef1

Comment: I've edited the post with debug output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [dotnet/corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimTypes.cs#L27):

```
public static class ClaimTypes
{
    internal const string ClaimTypeNamespace ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims";
    ....
    public const string Role = ClaimTypeNamespace + "/role";
    ...
```

The const **`ClaimTypes.Role`** is **`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`**

Note your controller requires a role of `offline_access`:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "offline_access")]
```

In other words, it expects the decoded `JWT` has a property of **`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`** to configure the roles:

```
{
  "nbf": ...,
  "exp": ...,
  "iss": ...,
  "aud": ...,
   ...,
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": [
    "offline_access",
    "...other roles"
  ],
}
```

However, you configure the roles in the following way:

```
   "realm_access":{  
      "roles":[  
         "offline_access",
         "uma_authorization"
      ]
   },
```

The easiest way is rebuild the token to config a role of `offline_access`:

```
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,"1024"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"offline_access"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"...other roles"),
        // ... other claims
    });

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken
    (
        issuer: _issuer,
        audience: _audience,
        claims: identity.Claims,
        expires: expiry,
        notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mykeyname)),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
    );

    var tokenStr = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Or you could transform the keycloak's style claim to Microsoft's style by registering a custom `IClaimsTransformation`, see a Sample by ASP.NET Core Team https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/658b37d2bd3b0da2c07e25b53fa5c97ce8d656d3/src/Security/samples/ClaimsTransformation/Startup.cs#L34

Comment: Since I'll be dealing with a few roles, would it make sense to implement a claims transformation so the pipeline will parse the keycloak jwt into a microsoft compatible token at every call?

Comment: @Thomas Yes. That's what  the `IClaimsTransformation` service is designed to do. [Every time the authentication succeeds](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/2e8ae438633d5b0008bf531e9fe3291257990e95/src/Http/Authentication.Core/src/AuthenticationService.cs#L72-L73), this service will be invoked.

Comment: I have tried to add the the claim transformer (I've edited the question), but it still gets rejected right away before reaching the transformer.

Comment: @Thomas For your last two edits:  "But I keep getting a 401, no matter what I try, I get a 401...:". Maybe I'm asking a stupid question : did you **enable the authentication middleware** by `app.UseAuthentication();` ?

Comment: yes, it is there; it's before UseMVC, but I tried to put it after too.

Comment: @Thomas I copy & paste your code, however it works fine for me. I also tried your expired JWT token (and set  the `ValidateLifetime = false) ,` it still works fine with `[Authorize]`. . If you're not writing not commercial code , could you please upload your project somewhere?

Comment: You can remove the call to OpenId.Initialize when testing because it's just calling our internal lib to interact with Keycloak, but there is no ASP code in it. The code you'll see that registers controllers and signalr hubs is to register them from plugin assemblies; I've tried to run the tests with these disabled as well and got the same result. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: @Thomas, Since you didn't upload the complete codes, I cannot run/debug it directly. But according to your code snippets, there's several potential reasons: 1. Your configuration are built to take Env variables only.  Could you please make sure the `AuthJWTPublicKey` is always the one you post above ? 2. I don't see how you post the request,  did you really add a header like `Authorization: Bearer xyz....` ? I'm asking this because I could authenticate your expired token if I set the `ValidateLifetime = false`.

Comment: @Thomas See a minimal demo that works : https://send.firefox.com/download/43c106a71f57468f/#vKNv0LUEEgCDJw8n_T5J9A

Comment: it works! I found a couple issues on my end using your test code; one of them was a very basic mistake on our end since we interface with keycloak: no space between 'Bearer' and the JWT :) thanks a lot for spending the time on this and making some sample code, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is stored in the variable but it looks like it's not a private token:

```
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AuthJWTPublicKey)),
```

This is as far as I know a private symmetric key, perhaps you are passing a wrong value in there?

Comment: It's the key to decode the token; the key is valid for sure, but maybe how it is passed is not

Comment: I just verified the key and it is not a problem, it matches the one in Keycloak

Comment: yes, I did, it validates; but I found another potential issue: https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/issues/134/token-created-by-keycloak-cannot-be  I don't know if it affects ASP

Answer (score 0):

You can modify keycloak configuration for JWT creation to map the roles to "roles" item instead grouping under "realm_access".

This can be done by adding a Mapper in Keycloak client.

This works for me:

[Keycloak Mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMCIK.png)

You can also create a second Mapper for "User Client Role". Just select "User Client Role" for Mapper Type.